# Send reminder email with a windows service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-services

We have an ASP.NET MVC web app that we have installed in several clients/domains (more than 100). This web app works with MS SQL database running in a Windows server. All the domains are in the same service and running in separate databases in the same MS SQL server.

Each client can create events for their users. We are talking some days one client could have more than 200 events.

We need to create a Window service to be running on the server where all the clients are to send, every few hours, reminder emails of each event for each client.

As I explained before each client has its own database and there is a common database with all the clients information and their database names.

What the service has to do is check, for each client, the events they have and send the corresponding emails.

We don't know if is better to have one service to go through all the clients or have a service per client. If we have just one service we would have to run it , for example, every 6 hours sending those emails.

In case we have a service per client we would need to create the service from the asp.net web app, would it be possible?

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: If your apps are going to send notifications to ONE central db, then it would make sense to only have one Windows Service. Just that the notification is stored with it's destination so the service can send them back to the correct client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Integration Service to do this job. All you need to write a SSIS package and schedule it.

On each execution of this package you can check data and send emails accordingly.

I hope this idea will help.